# Find the largest difference in every subarray [i, j]

Tags: arrays, algorithm, array-algorithms

I have an array `p` with integers .
I need to compute `d[i, j] for all (i, j) : i<j` , where :
 `d[i, j] = max (p[b] - p[a]) , i<=a<b<=j`

I know how to solve this for `d[1,n]` in O(n) . But for every pair ?  Here's my thoughts:

- I can solve it in O(n^3) : Basically I can use the solution for d[1, n] for every subarray : Let's say I want d[i, j]:

```py
right = j 
left = i
mx = p[j]
mn = p[i] 
while(left < right):
    if(p[right] > mx)
       mx = p[right]
    if(p[left] < mn)
      mn = p[left]
    right--; left ++;
return (mx-mn)
```

Now I can repeat for every pair : #pairs = n^2 and therefore O(n^3).
But there must be something faster.

- I can see that if  `d[i, j] = p[m] - p[l]` then `d[a, b] = d[i, j] for all a <=  m < l <=b` (basically the [l, m] is contained in [a, b])
- I can also see that if d[i, j] = p[m]-p[l] and m < j and l > i then this difference will get bigger iff there exists : p[q] < p[l] or p[m]
- Since , I need to solve n^2 subproblems even if I solve them in O(1), the time complexity has a lower bound to write these results so `T(n) = Ω(n^2)` 
  Can you help ?

Comment: Your `d[i, j]` solution is wrong.

Comment: What is your expected time complexity?

Comment: I guess O(n^2) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can compute `d[i, j] = max (p[b] - p[a]) , i<=a<b<=j` for a fixed `i` in linear time i.e, `O(n)`. How?

Let us say that we have a array called `values` of size `n`

- Now, fix the starting index(`startIndex`). This is same as fixing `i`
- traverse from `startIndex` to end of the array

  - while traversing keep track of the minimum value(`minValue`) and also the maximum difference(`maxDiff`) encountered so far
  - at any index say `endIndex`, the largest possible difference in the range `[startIndex,endIndex]` is just `max(maxDiff, values[endIndex] - minValue)`

If we repeat the above approach for each index by fixing it as the `startIndex`, then we can compute largest possible difference for all the sub-arrays of any given array in `O(n^2)`

```cpp
// implementation of above approach in C++
vector<vector<int>> findLargestDiff(vector<int>& values) {
    int n = values.size();

    vector<vector<int>> largestDiff(n, vector<int>(n));

    for (int startIndex = 0; startIndex < n; startIndex++) {
        int minValue = values[startIndex];
        int maxDiff = 0;

        for (int endIndex = startIndex; endIndex < n; endIndex++) {
            minValue = min(minValue, values[endIndex]);

            maxDiff = max(maxDiff, values[endIndex] - minValue);

            largestDiff[startIndex][endIndex] = maxDiff;
        }
    }

    return largestDiff;
}
```